# Why make a big boilerplate rather than just import and export file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a library and I'm trying to understand the logic inside. I'm wondering why they have choosen to make a big boilerplate to export some file rather than just `import... export {...}` like we make it often.

Here the index.js file :

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});
exports.typeCheck = exports.react = exports.keyboardEvent = undefined;

var _keyboardEvent2 = require('./keyboard-event');

var _keyboardEvent = _interopRequireWildcard(_keyboardEvent2);

var _react2 = require('./react');

var _react = _interopRequireWildcard(_react2);

var _typeCheck2 = require('./type-check');

var _typeCheck = _interopRequireWildcard(_typeCheck2);

function _interopRequireWildcard(obj) {
    if (obj && obj.__esModule) {
        return obj;
    } else {
        var newObj = {};
        if (obj != null) {
            for (var key in obj) {
                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) newObj[key] = obj[key];
            }
        }
        newObj.default = obj;
        return newObj;
    }
}

exports.keyboardEvent = _keyboardEvent;
exports.react = _react;
exports.typeCheck = _typeCheck;
```

They could done the thing like that :

```
'use strict';

var _keyboardEvent = require('./keyboard-event');
var _react = require('./react');
var _typeCheck = require('./typeCheck');


exports.keyboardEvent = _keyboardEvent;
exports.react = _react;
exports.typeCheck = _typeCheck;
```

If someone has an idea about the reason to make the boilerplate, would be great,

thanks

Comment: Looks to me like that file was generated by babel from a file that likely used es6 imports/exports.

Comment: Import, export ( and a bunch of other ES6+ features ) are not supported 100% natively yet, so alot of people use babel and other transpilers to transform newer javascript into older javascript. So when all browsers supports it natively, you don't need a rewrite to take advantage of the new features.

Comment: effectively could be a transpiler process, the files are in the dist folder of the subpackage ° they have a modular project-structure ° furthermore there is effectively babel only installed in the subpackage together with react... okay so using just module.exports all this boilerplate is no longer useful, very interesting